# VF Page with Data Category filters - not able to select dropdown choice

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page on Knowledge that filters articles based on 4 data categories. The filters were side by side.  I added a right hand sidebar to the page and now the 4 filters are stacked 2X2. However when I click the top category filter and try to select by mousing down, the filter below it opens and the top one closes. I cannot select anything.

Can this be fixed? Possibly force the top filter to stay open? Or can I reduce the width of the filters so all 4 are in one row?

If relevant: this page is part of our Site.com community and lives inside an iFrame. Thanks!

[image: VF dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I got some help from another source and they advised that I use z-index to bring the dropdowns to the front. Works like a charm.

I'm new here, should I answer my own question? Seems better than deleting it.